# Generics program to access WCF service from client

Tags: c#, generics

Please look at the below code where a client is accessing WCF service

**Function GetPriority**

```
public List<Priority> GetPriority()
        {
            List<Priority> lstPriority = new List<Priority>();

            using (TmsServiceClient client = new TmsServiceClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    lstPriority =  client.GetPriority();
                }
                catch (FaultException<TMSCustomException> myFault)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myFault.Detail.ExceptionMessage);
                    client.Abort();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    client.Abort();                  
                }
            }
            return lstPriority;
        }
```

**Function GetStatus:**

```
public List<Status> GetStatus()
    {
        List<Status> lstStatus = new List<Status>();
        using (TmsServiceClient client = new TmsServiceClient())
        {
            try
            {
                lstStatus =  client.GetStatus();
            }
            catch (FaultException<TMSCustomException> myFault)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myFault.Detail.ExceptionMessage);
                client.Abort();                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                client.Abort();                   
            }
        }

        return lstStatus;
    }
```

Both the methods are working fine. As can be seen that there are many similarities between the two methods and they differ only at the time of method invocation and return type. Can this be make generic? If so how to do so? Or any other better way so that the catch exception block code should not be repeated everytime.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily refactor almost entire `Get ...` method into generic one. The only real variable part is which client method to call, which can be easily solved using [`Func<T,TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

```
private List<T> Get<T>(Func<TmsServiceClient, List<T>> clientCall)
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    using (TmsServiceClient client = new TmsServiceClient())
    {
        try
        {
            // invoke client method passed as method parameter
            results = clientCall(client);
        }
        catch (FaultException<TMSCustomException> myFault)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myFault.Detail.ExceptionMessage);
            client.Abort();                   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            client.Abort();                   
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Now your methods implementations look like this:

```
public List<Status> GetStatus()
{
    return Get<Status>(client => client.GetStatus());
}

public List<Priority> GetPriority()
{
    return Get<Priority>(client => client.GetPriority());
}
```

**Edit in response to OP comment**:

[`Func<TmsServiceClient, List<T>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) passed as a parameter to `Get<T>` method is a [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegate_%28.NET%29). Delegate is kind of function pointer - an object you use to *delegate* some actions to be executed later (hence the name).

`Func<TmsServiceClient, List<T>>` is basically a delegate that takes one input argument (of `TmsServiceClient` type) and returns `List<T>` as a result.

Now, what we do in for example `GetStatus`? We create an instance of such delegate (via [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)) - and we "tell" it to execute *`GetStatus()` method on `Client` object, which we will provide*:

```
    // this line works the same as in example above
    //                  Take client as parameter    call its .GetStatus method
    return Get<Status>((TmsServiceClient client) => client.GetStatus());
```

And that exactly what happens in

```
    // invoke client method passed as method parameter
    results = clientCall(client);
```

line. The delegate executes method we asked for.

Comment: I could not understand the part Func<TmsServiceClient... could you please explain

Comment: @user1025901: `Func<TmsServiceClient, List<T>>` is a delegate - check my edit.