# How to combine a) MEF and Generics in MEF composition engine?

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I have the below program in MEF

**Method 1:**

```
public ObjectResult<PartnerListingStatement> GetCommissionListingRecords(string uRL, PortalConstant.DataSourceType DataSourceType)
        {  

            ObjectResult<PartnerListingStatement> lstCommissionPartner = null;

            var dataPlugin = DataPlugins.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Metadata["SQLMetaData"].ToString() == DataSourceType.EnumToString());

            if (dataPlugin != null)
            {
                lstCommissionPartner = dataPlugin.Value.GetCommissionListingRecords(uRL);
            }
            return lstCommissionPartner;
        }
```

**Method B**

```
public ObjectResult<CommissionEarned> GetCommissionPaidToPartners(string uRL, PortalConstant.DataSourceType DataSourceType)
        {
            ObjectResult<CommissionEarned> lstCommissionEarned = null;

            var dataPlugin = DataPlugins.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Metadata["SQLMetaData"].ToString() == DataSourceType.EnumToString());

            if (dataPlugin != null)
            {
                lstCommissionEarned = dataPlugin.Value.GetCommissionPaidToPartners(uRL);
            }
            return lstCommissionEarned;
        }
```

Using generics or the like can these two be combined. Also the data types are different.
N.B.~ This question is different than [Generics program to access WCF service from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818086/generics-program-to-access-wcf-service-from-client)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question to ask after asking "Can I combine these methods?" is "What do these methods have in common?"  I your case, the answer to that would be something like this:

```
public ObjectResult<***SomeType***> GetValues(string uRL, PortalConstant.DataSourceType DataSourceType)
{
    ObjectResult<***SomeType***> ret = null;

    var dataPlugin = DataPlugins.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Metadata["SQLMetaData"].ToString() == DataSourceType.EnumToString());

    if (dataPlugin != null)
    {
        ret = dataPlugin.Value.***SomeMethod***(uRL);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

where `***SomeType***` and `***SomeMethod***` are the two meaningful differences between the methods.  The deal with the type, make the method generic and replace all the `***SomeType***` with the generic parameter.  To deal with the method, add a delegate parameter to the method.  Based on its usage, the delegate will be of the `Func<PluginType, string, ObjectResult<***SomeType***>>` type where PluginType is whatever type `dataPlugin.Value` is.  Now you have:

```
public ObjectResult<T> GetValues<T>( //do come up with a better name
    string uRL, 
    PortalConstant.DataSourceType DataSourceType,
    Func<PluginType, string, ObjectResult<T>> resultSelector)
{
    ObjectResult<T> ret = null;

    var dataPlugin = DataPlugins.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Metadata["SQLMetaData"].ToString() == DataSourceType.EnumToString());

    if (dataPlugin != null)
    {
        ret = resultSelector(dataPlugin.Value, uRL);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

which is changes GetCommissionListingRecords to (the generic type should be inferred)

```
GetValues(uRL, DataSourceType, (p, u) => p.GetCommissionListingRecords(u));
```

and similarly for the other method.

Comment: Not able to get this into work...the data pulgin is  [ImportMany]
        public System.Lazy<IDataAccess, IDictionary<string, object>>[] DataPlugins { get; set; }

Comment: In that case what will come in the PluginType?

Comment: Ok i solved it.. i need to pass the interface..thanks for ur explanation